# How to let users ping admins rails devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want users to be able to send an alert to admins when they click a button. Kind of "help me", message. Ive looked and I know you do some if else statement with current_user.admin? but I dont know where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very basic implementation would be something like having a model called `HelpTicket` and when a user pressed the Help Me button it creates a new Ticket in the database.

Then you can either have something that emails the Admins whenever there's a new ticket and/or you could check whenever the Admins log in if there are unanswered tickets and notify them.

## Userside

```
 # create_help_tickets_table_migration.rb
 create_table :help_tickets do |t|
   t.integer :user_id
   t.text :description
   t.integer :status, default: 0
   t.timestamps null: false
 end

 # help_ticket.rb
 class HelpTicket < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   enum :status, [:unanswered, :completed]
 end

 # help_tickets_controller.rb
 class HelpTicketsController < ApplicationController
   def create
     ticket = HelpTicket.new(params.permit(:description))
     ticket.user_id = current_user
     render :ok if ticket.save
   end
 end
```

## Adminside

```
# application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController
  before_action :check_help_tickets, if: Proc.new { current_user.admin? }


  def check_help_tickets
    flash[:notice] = "There are unattended help tickets" if HelpTicket.unanswered.exists?
  end
end
```

Hope this gives you a direction, good luck.